# Syncing variables across two separate web pages

Tags: javascript, variables, synchronization

In short, I had a scoreboard application written in HTML and Javascript that contained a timer, home name, guest name, home score, guest score, and period. I was able to make a display webpage without buttons (see image) and a controller webpage with buttons. Using Dropbox Datastores API, I was able to control the display webpage with the controller webpage. Now that the Datastores API is no longer working, I need a different way of syncing the variables across the webpages. Any thoughts on how I could do this? I was thinking about using a database.

[image: Display Webpage]

[image: Controller Webpage]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store the data for the current browser, I'd offer [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) as a solution. Otherwise, yes, sending the data to a database is appropriate.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm looking for cross device compatibility too. Do you recommend any APIs that deal with databases?

Comment: Probably you want something like Firebase[1] that doesn't require any custom backend code -- I gather that this would be similar to whatever datastore API you were using previously. But if you have access to your own HTTP server/backend code, you have lots and lots of database options. Let us know what other thoughts/questions you have, this is a very big topic area. [1]https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Looking at Firebase right now. I'll have to look up some tutorials on it. As for an HTTP server, I do have a Raspberry Pi with an Apache server with PHPMyAdmin that can handle this but I don't know how to set that up.

Comment: Sounds like a 'hosted' solution like Firebase or similar would fit the bill nicely then, ease of use and all